# Np.linalg.norm rounding gives weird results in comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, comparison, rounding

I'm implementing the DBSCAN algorithm in Python and have to compare distances between points to a given threshold :

```
    Neighbours = []
    for i,P in enumerate(X):
        print(np.linalg.norm(P - Q))
        if (np.linalg.norm(Q-P)) <= eps:
            print("ok")
            Neighbours += [i]
```

However with epsilon = 0.1 and this simple dataset : 
`X = np.array([[-10.1,-20.3], [2.0, 1.5], [4.3, 4.4], [4.3, 4.6], [4.3, 4.5], [2.0, 1.6], [2.0, 1.4]])`

Here's a portion of the output (the points are taken one by one and compared to the others in the dataset) :

```
0.0
ok
24.9329099786
28.5910825259
28.76404005
28.6775173263
25.0203916836
24.8455227355
24.9329099786
0.0
ok
3.70135110466
3.86005181312
3.78021163429
0.1
0.1
28.5910825259
3.70135110466
0.0
ok
0.2
0.1
ok
3.6235341864
3.78021163429
28.76404005
3.86005181312
0.2
0.0
ok
0.1
ok
3.78021163429
3.94081209905
28.6775173263
3.78021163429
0.1
ok
0.1
ok
0.0
ok
3.70135110466
```

As you can see sometimes the comparison with 0.1 works (the "ok" statement proves it) and the point is added to the neighbour list but sometimes it doesn't work at all and I'm completely clueless about it.
If I add a small amount like 0.001 it works as intended. Is there some rounding problem involved ?

Comment: What version of numpy? Newer versions (>=1.14) show more precision when printing floats, I think. You'd do better not to calculate the norm twice, also.

Comment: I updated to 1.15 and found out that the 0.1 that were not working were some 0.10000000000000009.
Thanks for you help !